# How to fix embedded Tableau error code 16?

Tags: jwt, tableau-api

**My project**

I'm trying to allow users to log into my site using their own site credentials and then view a private embedded Tableau Cloud workbook. I want to authorize this via a JWT + Connected App so that a user doesn't have to log in twice (ie first to my site, then to Tableau).

**Details**

In my Flask prototype, a user can log in and a JWT is created by PyJWT. This JWT is passed to the HTML code that Tableau provides for embedded workbooks. The project I'm testing is a Tableau Sample. I also have Creator permissions on the project.

**My problem**

The JWT doesn't work, and the user is asked to sign in again by Tableau. Tableau also gives an error code 16, which documentation says is caused by an invalid subject or expiration time. However, when the JWT is not passed at all, Tableau still gives an error code 16. Specifically, for both cases, it says:

- tableau_error_code: 0x285DFA77
- tableau_error_source: Client
- tableau_service_name: Unknown_Service
- tableau_status_code: 16

**What I've tried so far**

I think the issue is caused by one of two things:

1. The JWT is not being passed correctly (HTML below). Documentation is not clear about how to do this in Python
2. The JWT is invalid

To solve 1, I've passed the token in as many ways as possible.

To solve 2, I've tested the JWT on jwt.io and it seems correct. In any case the code I am using to generate it (shown below) is copy-pasted from the Tableau documentation.

Other things I've done:

- checked that JWT credentials are correct
- checked that the Connected App is enabled
- tried different expiry times for the JWT (1min, 10min, etc)
- different browsers, including browsers with no Tableau cookies

However none of these have worked or given me any clues as to what the issue could be. Is anyone able to help please?

Embedded HTML:

```
 <div class='tableauPlaceholder' token={{jwt_token}} style='width: 958px; height: 1230px;'>
        <object class='tableauViz' token={{jwt_token}} width='958' height='1230' style='display:none;'>
     <param name='host_url' token={{jwt_token}} value='https%3A%2F%2Fprod-uk-a.online.tableau.com%2F' />
     <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' />
     <param name='token' value={{jwt_token}} />
     <param name='site_root' value='&#47;t&#47;mysiteroot' />
     <param name='name' value='Regional&#47;GlobalTemperatures' />
     <param name='tabs' value='yes' />
     <param name='toolbar' value='yes' />
     <param name='showAppBanner' value='false' />
```

JWT creation code:

```
    token = jwt.encode(
        {
            "iss": client_id,
            "exp": datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1),
            "jti": str(uuid.uuid4()),
            "aud": "tableau",
            "sub": "myTableauEmail",
            "scp": ["tableau:views:embed", "tableau:metrics:embed"]
        },
            secret,
            algorithm = "HS256",
            headers = {
            'kid': secret_id,
            'iss': client_id,
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came across a similar issue during my attempt to use jwt for API authentication.
In general you have to

1. generate a jwt
2. sign-in with the generated token to get a session token (similar to username/password approach)

Important to note here is that the documentation states to use following as subject.

> User name (email address) of the authenticated Tableau Cloud user.

This seems to be wrong. Only when I use **just** my username, **without** domain, the whole process works.

Here is how I do it (shortened and simplified version)

```py
import uuid

import jwt
import pendulum

now = pendulum.now(tz='UTC')
expire = now.add(seconds=session_token_lifetime)

_jwt = jwt.encode(
    payload=dict(
        iss=client_id,
        exp=now.add(seconds=60),
        jti=str(uuid.uuid4()),
        aud='tableau',
        sub=user_name_without_domain,
        scp=scopes,
    ),
    key=private_key,
    algorithm='HS256',
    headers=dict(kid=private_key_id, iss=client_id),
)

response = _api.signin(  # api/3.17/auth/signin
    json=dict(
        credentials=dict(
            jwt=_jwt,
            site=dict(contentUrl=''),  # site-name here
            user=dict(id=user_name_without_domain),
        ),
    ),
)

session_token = response['credentials']['token']
site_id = response['credentials']['site']['id']
```

Note that I specifically set headers to contain following, to be able to send and receive json instead of xml.

```py
{'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
```

My running tableau version:

```py
{
 "serverInfo": {
  "productVersion": {
   "value": "2022.3.4",
   "build": "20223.23.0214.1014"
  },
  "prepConductorVersion": "2022.3.1",
  "restApiVersion": "3.17"
 }
}
```